# Java- How do i convert a string of numbers to an Array of letters

Tags: java, split

This is what I want to do:

I want to be able   at the prompt just type in some numbers like

> input
>
> 10 10 20 30

After that I would like to convert each number to a letter so my output would be like

jjte

Here is my code. Currently all I get is null.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Past in code here: ");
       Scanner inputM=new Scanner(System.in);
       String  input=inputM.nextLine();
       String[] Emessage=input.split(" ");
       String[] eMessage=new String[Emessage.length];

       for(int i = 0; i < Emessage.length; i++) {
          if(Emessage[i]=="10"){eMessage[i]="a";}
          if(Emessage[i]=="20"){eMessage[i]="b";}
          if(Emessage[i]=="30"){eMessage[i]="c";}
          if(Emessage[i]==" "){eMessage[i]=" ";}           
       } 

       System.out.println(" ");

       for(int i=0;i<eMessage.length;i++){
           System.out.print(eMessage[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

This is a sample run:
.......................

> Past in code here:
>
> 10 20 30
>
> nullnullnull

Note: nullnullnull   should equal   abc

Comment: `==` is to compare references `equals()` is to compare values and this is what you need

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
    if (Emessage[i].equals("10") {
        //code
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much TtymeJV   THAT did the trick.   I'm new to java so there you go. I'm working on an app that encrypt text and email messages.

Comment: to clarify tyme's answer, == only returns true if both strings refer back to the same object and memory location. sometimes when java creates two strings with the same value, it'll reuse that memory location reference, so it'll work, but as you can see it's unreliable

Answer (score 1):

Since String is an object ,ou can't check equality of string using == operator. you need to use equals method for checking equality as follows

```
if( "10".equals( Emessage[i] ) ){ eMessage[i]="a"; }
```